# Skewed Edges for multiple lines in headline

Tags: css, transform, skew

I ran into a little css problem. I'm trying to get skewed edges for a headline, which also workes for multiple lines (see in [added screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sTvs.png)). Important: The skewed edge should appear on every single line.

I already tried following solutions which didn't work 100%:

- `:after, :before` Elements as Triangles or parallelogram (https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

```css
.element {
    background: red;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}

.element:after {
        background: #f00;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        transform: skew(-20deg);
        position: absolute;
        right: -5px;
        top: 0;
        width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Headline 1</div>
<div class="element">Headline 2 veeery long</div>
```

--> doesn't work for multiple line because it needs to meet the bottom-right top-left corner

- Multi-Line Padded Text (https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/) with skewed edges 
  --> doesn't work to make it skewed on the edges without pseudo-element. same problem like above.

Can you help me with a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried it using background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with display inline:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  max-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 46px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(110deg, transparent 50%, red 53%), linear-gradient(110deg, red 50%, transparent 53%), linear-gradient(to left, red, red);
  background-size: 16px 100%, 16px 100%, calc(100% - 32px) 100%;
  background-position: left, right, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 16px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
          box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div><h1>Some dynamic text on several lines with no special meaning...</h1></div>
```

No Edge support for now as "box-decoration-break" is not supported (yet?).

Comment: So great! That's what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you link provided,
This according to me is best answer... ( hope so )
Increasing the element width as I did in below code snippet ,

```
    width: 200px;
```

Will work fine with the way you want [Sample Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVbYw.png)

View `Code snippet` in full screen

```css
.element {
    background: red;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding : 10px ;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}

.element:after {
        background: #f00;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        transform: skew(-10deg);
        position: absolute;
        right: -5px;
        top: 0;
        width: 50px;
}
.element:before {
        background: #f00;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        transform: skew(-10deg);
        position: absolute;
        left: -5px;
        top: 0;
        width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Headline 1</div>
<div class="element">Headline 2 veeery long</div>
<div class="element">Headline</div>
<div class="element">Another Headline</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for every line... I need skewed edge for every single line as you can see in the added screen.

Comment: *As I can see in added screen* ~ I have edited my answer , hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you out. Here just applied linear gradient to in before and after element and positioned them absolute. Its height will increase according to the height of relative div.

In case you want to increase the curved area you just need to update width and position them left and right as per the amount of given width. As done in example.

```css
.element {
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
    psdding: 10px;
    background: #f00;
    padding: 10px;
}

.element:after, .element:before {
     
        content: "";
        width: 10px;
        position:absolute;
        height: 100%;
        
        
}
.element:before {
 top: 0px; background: linear-gradient(to top left, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
 left: -10px;
}
.element:after {
 top: 0px; background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
 right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Headline 1</div>
<div class="element">Headline 2 veeery long</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for every line... I need skewed edge for every single line as you can see in the added screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple background and rely on the repeat:

```css
.element {
  background: red;
  margin:10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  padding:0 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 50%,transparent 0)100% 0/30px 30px repeat-y,
  linear-gradient(to top left,red 50%,transparent 0)0 0/30px 30px repeat-y,
  linear-gradient(red,red)30px 0/calc(100% - 60px) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Headline 1</div>
<div class="element">Headline 2 veeery long</div>
<div class="element">Headline 2 veeery long veeery long veeery long</div>
```